# struggling for days to sort php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been struggling for days with php array's.
Somehow I don't get it to sort $my_array.

What I like to achieve is:

1. read data from a mysql table [that works]
2. place the data in my_array [that works]
3. calculate a value based on data from that table and add that in my_array [that works]
4. sort the array on the 'calculated' value in step 3. [failed this one]

I managed 1 to 3 but not step 4.

below is simplified php code

```
//table contents in mysql table
//---------------------
//alfa, 5, 2
//beta, 18, 3
//gamma, 7, 2
$q="SELECT * FROM model";
$result=mysql_query($q);
$total=mysql_numrows($result); 

$i=0;
while ($i<$total)
    {
    $modelname=mysql_result($status,$i,"modelname");
    $volume=mysql_result($result,$i,"volume");
    $force=mysql_result($result,$i,"force");

    $my_array[$i][0]=$modelname;
    $my_array[$i][1]=$volume;
    $my_array[$i][2]=$force;

    //below the calculated value what I like to sort on later in the code
    $my_array[$i][3]=$value1/$value2; /results are values like 2.5, 6, 3.5

    $i++;
}

// contents of $my_array so far:
//$i, $modelname, $volume, $force, calculated result
//---------------------
// 0, alfa, 5, 2, 2.5
// 1, beta, 18, 3, 6
// 2, gamma, 7, 2, 3.5
// now how to sort my_array on the last element [3]?
// must I use sort, usort and how to sort on this fourth value?


//epected result in my_array (sort ascending on the last element)
//first element is the index in the array (used with $i)
//---------------------
//0, alfa, 5, 2, 2.5
//1, gamma, 7, 2, 3.5
//2, beta, 18, 3, 6
```

Comment: Strip out all that MySQL code, please, and replace it with example arrays that you create by hand. It would mean we could run your code on our machines and test the fix does what you want.

Comment: Why you don't sort data by MySQL query?

Comment: splash58: because what I like to sort is not part of the data in the database. A calculation is mandatory before it can be sorted.

Comment: where exactly are `$value1` & `$value2` coming from in the division? I would bet that you could probably achieve all of this in the original sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple code:

```
$my_array = array(
    array( 'alfa', 5, 2, 2.5 ),
    array( 'beta', 18, 3, 6 ),
    array( 'gamma', 7, 2, 3.5 ),
);

usort($my_array, function($a, $b) { return $a[3] - $b[3]; });
print_r($my_array);
```

`usort` callback explanation:

- as explained in manual `usort` callback takes two arguments, which are some items of `$my_array`. As each item of `$my_array` is an array too, you can use standard syntax for accessing elements of an array, in this case `$a[3]`
- next, you need to return a result of  comparison. As explained in manual

  > The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less 
  >   than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So, subtracting `$a[3] - $b[3]` does this. If `$a[3] < $b[3]` - result of substraction is negative, else - positive, so compare function returns just what you need. Of course, you can use example function from php manual and write something like:

```
function($a, $b) { return $a[3] < $b[3]? -1 : 1; }
```

and it still will work, but `$a[3] - $b[3]` does the same and takes less code.

Comment: this usort does the job, very happy, but have to be honest that I don't understand yet the syntax (while reading usort documentation). I suspect return $a[3] - $b[3]  means compare the values of the 3rd (last) element in the array (that I like to sort)? Looking to http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php I can't match your solution to one of the examples.

Comment: @incognito Added an explanation.